# RESTFul Service and cross domain calls

Tags: rest, post, cross-domain, jsonp

To be really RESTFul, a service should comply to REST rules such as using the correct http operation (GET, POST, PUT etc..) for each scenario, e.g use POST to create a new resource or GET to get a resource without modifying the global state.

However, cross-domain calls that use the JSONP approach works only with GET operation by nature.

How do you do to both respect REST rules (meaning we can have some methods that will be accessible only by POST ing a data to them) and make your service accepting cross domain calls ? Is there some best practices to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Riana

Comment: Are you able to change configuration on the server and the client? If so, you can configure the server to accept [cross-origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) requests from specific domains, thereby still adhering to strict REST rules.

Comment: I can change configuration for our debbuging server only. I'm looking for a more lightweight solution if possible ... Thanks !